# Business Account does not appear as an option during the verification process

Tags: facebook

I'm attempting to verify a business for an app in the Meta for Developers platform. I have been added to business account by the owner, and I can select the business account in the top right.

However, the business does not appear as an option when I attempt to verify it (the only option is another business).[image: image showing that the business is not an option]

Should it appear here, or is this expected behavior?

(The app is created under my own account rather the business account - I believe you cannot create an app under a business account).